# arXiv messing up bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, pdftex, arxiv

I'm having a little trouble with a submission to arXiv and I don't know if people here can help diagnose it. Simply put, the arXiv tex compiler is screwing up the bibliography for reasons I don't understand.

In the paper.bbl file for paper.tex, you have entries such as:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citename{Mitchell and Lapata}2008]{mitchell2008vector}
J.~Mitchell and M.~Lapata.
\newblock 2008.
\newblock {Vector-based models of semantic composition}. 
\newblock In {\em Proceedings of ACL}, volume~8.
```

When I compile the paper with `pdflatex`, I obtain bibliography items such as:

[image: Citations in local version]

However, when I upload the tex to arxiv (along with all the accompanying files, and with the macro `\pdfoutput=1` at the top of the tex document) I get the following output for the same bibliography item.

[image: Citations on arXiv]

As you can see, it's adding the information from the `bibitem` option into the references themselves. Does anyone have any idea how I can get arXiv's pdflatex to stop doing this? Am I doing something wrong on my end, or should I contact arXiv and tell them something is broken on their end?

If it helps. here's the tex log generated by arxiv: http://pastebin.com/uCFBzuiH

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

**Edit:** Answer to this problem provided by Lev Bishop in the comments below. Just make a file `00README.XXX` with the line `nohypertex` in it.

Comment: The arxiv output you show is the output I would expect from the bbl input that you posted. `\bibitem` is like `\item` and its optional argument is usually printed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: According to http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/bibliographies.html the [args] allow the specification of how the citations are labeled in text. Is there not a way to surpress their appearance in the bibliography? Why are they not appearing when I run pdflatex locally?

Comment: To answer my own question, the document is using the acl2013 style (http://acl2013.org/site/Latex/acl2013.sty) which has a section stating that it suppresses bibliography labels. The question is now, why is arXiv ignoring this part of the style file?

Comment: Just a guess: you could make a file `00README.XXX` with the line `nohypertex` in it. See [here](http://arxiv.org/help/00README#nohypertex)

Comment: @LevBishop: That worked! I have no idea why, but it did. Thanks :) Is there an explanation?

Comment: @LevBishop Please make that an answer (with some explanation)

Answer (score 5):

Make a file `00README.XXX` with the line `nohypertex` in it. The uses of the `00README.XXX` file are described [in the arXiv help](http://arxiv.org/help/00README).

By default arXiv processes files with HyperTeX (something like automatically adding `\usepackage[implicit]{hyperref}`), which can [occasionally conflict with certain classes and styles](http://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#nohypertex), as appears to be the case here.